# Regex to validate date format

Tags: regex, date, validation, parsing, map-force

I'm figuring out a way to validate my input date in Altva Mapforce which is in the format "YYYYMMDD".

I know to verify year I can use `[0-9]{4}` but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to "restrict" date range to "01-31" and month to "01-12". Please note "01" is valid while "1" should be invalid.

Can someone please provide a regex expression to validate this sort of input?

From searching internet I got one for month: `([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` but this one is valid for range 1-31. I want 01-31 and so on.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for the response. Can you please provide a  combined regex expression for YYYYMMDD? I tried merging all the three parts but it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a month from 1-12 adding a zero for a single digit 1-9:

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[012])
```

For a day 1-31 adding a zero for a single digit 1-9:

```
(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

Putting it all together with 4 digits to match a year (note that `\d{4}` can also match 0000 and 9999), enclosed in word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match with leading or trailing digits / word characters:

```
\b\d{4}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\b
```

A variation, limiting the scope for a year to for example 1900 - 2099

```
\b(?:19|20)\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\b
```

But **note** that this does not validate the date itself, it can for example also match `20210231`. To validate a date, use a designated api for handling  a date in the tool or code.

Comment: Very well described! And, the final **note** makes the answer even more useful.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks, dates and time always remind me to [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)